# How to chek Sqlserver and visual studio softwares are installed while installing msi file

Tags: deployment, wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

I am creating msi file using visual studio. But i need to know how to test .Net Framework and SQL server are installed before doing installation of msi.

Is there any settings (Or) any windows installer are available.

Comment: i am thiking using wix installer we can chaek for the softwares(.Net FW). I saw in this link :    http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/3a897533-e9d8-481a-9ea3-1205f427bfb2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer proposes use the Bootstrapping for these purposes. You pack your MSI to Setup.exe and set needed prerequisites, in your case .NET FW 4 and SQL. When user starts Setup.exe, it checks if .NET and SQL are installed, if not installs them and then run the your MSI. You could include the installation files of .NET or SQL in your setup.exe or set link from where installation downloads it.

There is more information about [Windows Installer Bootstrapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).